# Pug JS Express running a function from pug

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, pug

A pug file with button(onclick) run the function in js file, if both of the files are inside the public and views folder or both of the files are out of the views and public folders.

How can I run the function from the pug file;
When pug file in Views folder and js file in out of the public and views folders?

Thanks

```
pug file: In views folder
```

```
button.btn.btn-primary(onclick='myfunc()') Function 1
```

js file: out of views and public folders

```
function myfunc(){
    console.log('Hi');
  }
```

I try to run a function from a pug file with button(onclick)

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem.

In the pug file:

```
          form(action="/test" method="POST")                                    
                    .form-group
                        input(type="submit" value="submit").btn.btn-danger
```

In the JS file:

```
            export function posttest  (req, res, next) {

                const myfunc = () => {
                    console.log("hi");  
                }

                myfunc()
            }
```

And I added a route for posttest